# Why are random portions of data replacing my other data that was once stored in my character array?

Tags: c++, output, getline

I have a program which grabs data from an input file and formats it so it can be printed into an output file, so for example for input I have something like this that is meant to be put in a table format in my output file. I have multiple lines like this in my input file, all identical to this sort of format.

```
Homer Simpson 642084 100 99 20 5 15 77
```

My problem comes from the 6-digit number right after the name. For whatever strange reason, my program is not printing that number correctly after a certain point.

Here is what I believe to be the relevant code. It is still a WIP:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int dropped(int[]);
float avg(int[],int);
float avg_not_six(int[], float);
char give_grade(float);
int main() {

char first_name[11];
char last_name[13];
char lettergrade;
char I_D[7];
char score [6];
int nscore[5];
float grade_avg;
int lowest;
float gradechk=0.0;

ifstream inputfile;
ofstream outputfile;
inputfile.open("student_input.dat");
outputfile.open("student_results.dat");
//Error checking
if (!inputfile)
{
    cout<<"Error: Incorrect input file"<<endl;
}
// table formatting
outputfile<<"Last"<<right<<setw(8)<<"First"
<<right<<setw(8)<<"ID"<<right<<setw(10)<<"Average"
<<right<<setw(8)<<"Grade"<<endl;
outputfile<<endl;

while (!inputfile.eof()) {
   //continues to grab until end of file is reached
        inputfile.getline(first_name, 10, ' ');
        inputfile.getline(last_name, 12, ' ');
        inputfile.getline(I_D, 7, ' ');
        inputfile.getline(score, 20);

//converts scorees to ints and stores in array nscore
    nscore[0]=atoi(score);
    nscore[1]=atoi(score+3);
    nscore[2]=atoi(score+5);
    nscore[3]=atoi(score+8);
    nscore[4]=atoi(score+11);
    nscore[5]=atoi(score+14);

    //Finds lowest grade to be dropped
   lowest = dropped(nscore);

    // Detects missing grades and issues warning
    for (int i =0; i<=5; i++) {

        if (nscore[i]==0)
        {
            gradechk++;
            cout<<"Warning: Less than six grades are present"<<endl;
            grade_avg=avg_not_six(nscore,gradechk);

        }
        else
           grade_avg = avg(nscore, lowest);
        // If grade is negative, close program
        if (nscore[i]<0) {
            cout<<"Error: Negitive grade present"<<endl;;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    lettergrade=give_grade(grade_avg);

    //Reset counter
    gradechk=0;
}

    inputfile.close();
    outputfile.close();

 return 0;
}
```

Whenever I test to make sure that the 6-digit number is grabbed right after I use the getline on it (third down) by printing to the screen, it seems to work. However whenever I decide to tell it to print that number somewhere else in the code, it prints out this instead. Bear in mind that I have multiple lines in the input file.

```
76 93 9A 98
```

From what I can tell, these are pieces of data from different lines. I honestly have no idea why this is happening. If it helps, I am required to use the cstring library, and use functions like `atoi` and `getline`. If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Turn on your compilers warning options and it'll be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getline() that reads the last word of the line in your case reads only till the " " (space). Then the next getline reads till "\n"(newline character). Due to which your input is distorted.
Add an additional getline() at the end of each line to read the "\n" character.

Try doing this

```
        inputfile.getline(first_name, 10, ' ');
        inputfile.getline(last_name, 12, ' ');
        inputfile.getline(I_D, 7, ' ');
        inputfile.getline(score, 20);
        inputfile.getline(tempStr);
```

Comment: I’m sorry I’m fairly new to this. Is tempStr something I need to create or is it already a function?

Comment: You need to create that string variable.